# Chrome/jQuery bug with CSS layout/animation? Workaround?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, jquery-animate

In Chrome, the computed "top" property of an element may not be the same as the "top" property as specified by setting its style. This is causing me problems with animation. It seems that jQuery animate starts by looking up the current *computed* style, but it updates by setting the *specified* style.

I'd like to know how best to work around this.

I have created a
[simple example](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.wischik/Leftovers/test.html) of the problem. In Firefox, type in a value in the box, e.g. -500, then click Go, and it will animate the "top" property of the ruler so that the needle points to 500. Type in 499 and click Go, and the ruler will hardly change. Now try the same thing in Chrome, *with the zoom set to 83%*. When you go from 500 to 499, there will be a big jerk in the animation. This is because jQuery is starting from the computed top which is -416px, then animating it to the specified top which is -499px.

**Update.** One person suggested using percent values rather than pixel values for the animation. That works -- thanks! Is there a better way which will let me stick with my old pixel-based code?

Comment: Try 70 percent as top value for inner instead of an absolute value and see what happens.

Comment: Could you describe your goal? What is the animation supposed to do?

Comment: My animations move #inner up and down to specified pixel values. For example, I might animate #inner to -1000px, then to -1050px. You could think of #inner as displaying a big tall gauge, and there's a needle at a fixed position to one side of it.

Comment: When I use % values instead of pixels, then the computed "top" and the actual "top" are indeed equal. This solves my problem, thank you. (But it requires me to do yucky calculations, turning all my pixels into percentages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's a difference between style position and jQuery calculated position, then make jQuery calculate the start position before it begins, thus eliminating the difference. Assuming your style says the element is positioned at:

```
.mydiv {top:120px;}
```

But when you begin animating the div, Chrome thinks the element is at 111px instead...

So, have jQuery get the top position for your starting point, and animate from there instead.

```
var thePosition = $('div.mydiv').offset();
var endLeft = thePosition.left - 500;
var endTop = thePosition.top - 500;
$(div.mydiv').animate({top : endTop, left : endLeft}, 'fast', function(){
    // do something on end
});
```

Comment: instead of top, use `{"padding-top":"+=15px"}` to be relative